# If $A\in B(H)$ commutes with all self-adjoint operators, then $A=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $A\in B(H)$. Could anyone explain why the following assertion is true: if $A$ commutes with all self-adjoint operators, then $A=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

(If this is not true, an additional postulate that $A$ is self-adjoint could be added).

Comment: Hint: try it on rank-one operators.

Comment: Self-adjoint operators linearly span the space of all operators. So if you commute with all self-adjoint operators, you must commute with all operators.

Comment: (Also, this is not true as stated, because $A = \lambda I$ for any *complex* $\lambda$ commutes with all operators. And that is exactly what you get: $A$ commutes with all self-adjoints iff $A$ commutes with all operators iff $A = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. If you assume in addition that $A$ is self-adjoint, then of course $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.)